# Preamble problem for beamer

Tags: beamer, preamble

I have a preamble that goes:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

%opening
\title{}
\author{Sean Thrasher}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] 
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma} 
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem] {Corollary} 
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem] {Remark} 
\newtheorem{ass}[theorem] {Assumptions} 
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem] {Definition} 
\newtheorem{conj}[theorem]{Conjecture} 
\newtheorem{step}{STEP}
\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{Observation}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem] {Example}
\newtheorem{idea}[theorem]{Idea}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newcommand{\nn}{\in \mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\bv}{\bibitem}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cor}{Cor}

\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
```

and it is not rendering properly in beamer.

It says:
option clash for package geometry, option clash for package xcolor (for the inputenc package), and then it says \theorem, \lemma, \definition, \example are all already defined, and there is a missing \begin{document}.

Something does render, but it has "Theroem[section]" etc on the first page of the slide.

I don't have these issues when doing a normal document, so why is beamer having trouble with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of problems:

- beamer automatically defines the most commonly used theorems for you. If you don't want to use them and define your own theorems instead, you can use the `notheorems` class option. This way beamer knows to not define them.
- if your latex distribution outdated, using things like `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` in your preamble will cause an option clash error because beamer already loads packages like `xcolor`, `hyperref`, `graphicx`, `ams*` and many more. You can avoid this by either updating your latex distribution or using beamer class options like `xcolor={dvipsnames}` instead of loading these packages yourself.

In summary: don't copy your preamble from other classes to beamer. Instead only add the packages which you actually need to avoid such problems.

---

```
\documentclass[notheorems,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}

%opening
\title{}
\author{Sean Thrasher}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{braket}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] 
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma} 
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem] {Corollary} 
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem] {Remark} 
\newtheorem{ass}[theorem] {Assumptions} 
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem] {Definition} 
\newtheorem{conj}[theorem]{Conjecture} 
\newtheorem{step}{STEP}
\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{Observation}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem] {Example}
\newtheorem{idea}[theorem]{Idea}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newcommand{\nn}{\in \mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\bv}{\bibitem}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cor}{Cor}

\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```